# Install nvm / node on AMZ Linux 2 EC2 Instance with userData script

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-userdata

I'm trying to install nvm / node on an AMZ Linux 2 EC2 Instance using the following userData script:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash
. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 16.17.0
nvm use 16.17.0
```

However, when I SSH into the Instance, neither nvm nor node are installed. If I run the commands manually while SSH'd into the Instance, they work fine.

Anyone have any thoughts on why the installs don't work in the userData script? Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I still haven't figure out why the userData Script above doesn't work (it used to, so I'm not sure what changed), I was able to install Node using the following as userData, so I thought I'd share.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
yum update -y
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
yum install -y nodejs git
```

I'd still be interested to know why the first script no longer works, if anyone has any idea.

Cheers!

Rob

Comment: same here, none of these solutions on reddit helped me either https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/14t6j0h/install_nvm_node_on_amz_linux_2_ec2_instance_with/